# apache FileUpload and HttpClient headers encoding

Tags: java, file-io, file-upload, multifile-uploader

The question is about apache FileUpload servlet...

I am looking this answer for a long time but since nothing helped I need to get your advise. I have a servlet which gets FileItems uploaded... The thing is I want to send file name with header. It is pretty good with en file name letters but all goes wrong with non-en file name letters. For example if I get rus cirillic file name servlet gets file name as "<80-9~.flv" or something... so io.File doesn't want to save it as a file name because "it is not a file name" :) 
The question is how to control headers encoding if servlet gets headers from HttpClient?

Answer (score 1):

One of the first things you should do is set encoding on your client page to "UTF-8" -

```
post.addRequestHeader("ContentType", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
```

And also on your UploadServlet do -

```
 // Set character encoding in request
 request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

 // Get the file name after removing the path(this will ensure that you get the correct 
 //file name even in IE which sends the whole path)

 String fileName = org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.getName(fileItem.getName());
```

Setting it as UTF-8 ensures that all Cyrillic characters in file name also work.

Comment: I am using not jsp but HttpClient 4 desktop app :) So I haven't find how to set encoding with HttpClient 4? Please comment

Comment: Updated the above answer for HTTPClient.

Comment: Emm... But I use HttpPost. It doesn't contain any addRequestHeader method :( Is there an alt method for HttpPost?

Comment: Oh, my... It doesn't help :( I don't get it... My file name is still a "-(57**#.txt" or something. What I could do wrong? I am using HttpClient 4 (the last version) and there is so less snippets which demo the lib usage :(